# Error in if (!n.cat[i]) { : argument is of length zero

Tags: r

I just begin to learn to code using R and I tried to do a classification by C5.0. But I encounter some problems and I don't understand. I am looking for help with gratitude. Below is the code I learned from someone and I tried to use it to run my own data:

```
require(C50)

data.resultc50 <- c()

prematrixc50 <- c()

for(i in 3863:3993)

{

needdata$class <- as.factor(needdata$class)

trainc50 <- C5.0(class ~ ., needdata[1:3612,], trials=5, control=C5.0Control(noGlobalPruning = TRUE, CF = 0.25))

predc50 <- predict(trainc50, newdata=testdata[i, -1], trials=5, type="class")

data.resultc50[i-3862] <- sum(predc50==testdata$class[i])/length(predc50)

prematrixc50[i-3862] <- as.character.factor(predc50)

}
```

Belows are two objects `needdata` & `testdata` I used in the code above with part of their heads respectively:

```
    class Volume  MA20     MA10    MA120     MA40      MA340     MA24  BIAS10
1     1   2800    8032.00  8190.9  7801.867  7902.325  7367.976  1751   7.96
2     1   2854    8071.40  8290.3  7812.225  7936.550  7373.624  1766   6.27
3     0   2501    8117.45  8389.3  7824.350  7973.250  7379.444  1811   5.49
4     1   2409    8165.40  8488.1  7835.600  8007.900  7385.294  1825   4.02

# the above is "needdata" and actually has 15 variables with 3862 obs.

   class   Volume   MA20    MA10    MA120     MA40    MA340  MA24  BIAS10
1     1    2800     8032.00 8190.9 7801.867 7902.325 7367.976 1751   7.96
2     1    2854     8071.40 8290.3 7812.225 7936.550 7373.624 1766   6.27
3     0    2501     8117.45 8389.3 7824.350 7973.250 7379.444 1811   5.49
4     1    2409     8165.40 8488.1 7835.600 8007.900 7385.294 1825   4.02

# the above is "testdata" and has 15 variables with 4112 obs.
```

The data above contain the factor `class` with value of `0` & `1`. After I run it I got warnings below:

> In predict.C5.0(trainc50, newdata = testdata[i, -1], trials = 5,  ... :   'trials' should be <= 1 for this object. Predictions generated
>    using 1 trials

And when I try to look at the object `trainc50` just created, I noticed the number of boosting iterations is 1 due to early stopping as shown below:

```
# trainc50
Call:
C5.0.formula(formula = class ~ ., data = needdata[1:3612, ], 
             trials  = 5, control = C5.0Control(noGlobalPruning = TRUE, 
             CF = 0.25), earlyStopping = FALSE)

Classification Tree
Number of samples: 3612
Number of predictors: 15
Number of boosting iterations: 5 requested;  1 used due to early stopping
Non-standard options: attempt to group attributes, no global pruning
```

I also tried to plot the decision tree and I got the error as below:

```
plot(trainc50)
```

> Error in if (!n.cat[i]) { : argument is of length zero
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In 1:which(out == "Decision tree:") :   numerical expression has 2 elements: only the first used

Does that mean my code is too bad to perform further trials while running C5.0? What is wrong? Can someone please help me out about why do I encounter early stopping and what does the error and waring message mean? How can I fix it? If anyone can help me I'll be very thankful.

Comment: And I even don't know what does  (!n.cat[i]) and  "In 1:which(out == "Decision tree:")" mean...

Answer (score 0):

Used in 
http://r-project-thanos.blogspot.tw/2014/09/plot-c50-decision-trees-in-r.html

```
using function 
C5.0.graphviz(firandomf,
              "a.txt",
              fontname='Arial',
              col.draw='black',
              col.font='blue',
              col.conclusion='lightpink',
              col.question='grey78',
              shape.conclusion='box3d',
              shape.question='diamond',
              bool.substitute=c('None', 'yesno', 'truefalse', 'TF'), 
              prefix=FALSE,
              vertical=TRUE)
```

And in the command line:

```
pip install graphviz 
dot -Tpng ~plot/a.txt >~/plot/a.png
```